# How to display fixed number of entries in Vim's browse oldfiles

Tags: vim

I am newbie to Vim. I find browse old files displaying several entries (70 recently opened files). Is there some way to control the number of files that I want to see in my "browse oldfiles" list.

I did check Vim's help and there is no mention of how to control the number of entries ?

```
:ol[dfiles]     List the files that have marks stored in the viminfo
            file.  This list is read on startup and only changes
            afterwards with ":rviminfo!".  Also see |v:oldfiles|.
            The number can be used with |c_#<|.
            {not in Vi, only when compiled with the |+eval|
            feature}

:bro[wse] ol[dfiles][!]
            List file names as with |:oldfiles|, and then prompt
            for a number.  When the number is valid that file from
            the list is edited.
            If you get the |press-enter| prompt you can press "q"
            and still get the prompt to enter a file number.
            Use ! to abandon a modified buffer. |abandon|
            {not when compiled with tiny or small features}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By setting `viminfo`. So for example, to set maximum number, say 70, of previously edited files

```
set viminfo='70
```

More info [`:h 'viminfo'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27viminfo%27).

Comment: Thanks. I missed the viminfo part in the help.

Answer (score 0):

I have just got a good solution https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/11829/7339

```
    :browse filter /pattern/ oldfiles
```

We can abreviate

```
    :bro filter /tips/ ol
```

This way your list will show only files with 'tips' on its names.